# In Android app, How can I add a button(It will open dialog menu) to every group in CursorTreeAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, listadapter, expandablelistadapter

I am developing a android application. So far it works. I am using CursorTreeAdapter in one place. I need to add button to groups in CursorTreeAdapter. I can add textview easily but when I add a button, my list doesnt work. It doesnt expand. How can I add a button properly?If it is possible, can you give me some code examples? I tried to make it to modify these two functions, but When I add button to my xml gorup file, my list doesnt expand.

```
@Override
    protected void bindGroupView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor,
            boolean isExpanded) {
        TextView text_line1 = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.work_list_group_view);
        text_line1.setText("title1");

        TextView text_line2 = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.work_list_group_view2);
        text_line2.setText("title2");

        ImageButton button = (ImageButton)    view.findViewById(R.id.context_menu_button);


    }

    @Override
    public View newGroupView(Context context, Cursor cursor,
            boolean isExpanded, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.work_list_expandable_group, parent, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void bindGroupView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor,
                             boolean isExpanded) { 
    TextView text_line1 = (TextView) view
             .findViewById(R.id.work_list_group_view);
    text_line1.setText("title1");

    text_line1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        // Open your dialog here 
    });

    TextView text_line2 = (TextView) view
             .findViewById(R.id.work_list_group_view2);
    text_line2.setText("title2");

    ImageButton button = (ImageButton) view
                .findViewById(R.id.context_menu_button);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void bindGroupView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isExpanded) {
    TextView text_line1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.work_list_group_view);
    text_line1.setText("title1");

    TextView text_line2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.work_list_group_view2);
    text_line2.setText("title2");

    ImageButton button = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.context_menu_button);
    // Magic comes here, you should add:
    button.setFocusable(false); // ListItem is not clickable if it has focusable child's.
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ ... });

}

@Override
public View newGroupView(Context context, Cursor cursor,
        boolean isExpanded, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.work_list_expandable_group, parent, false);
}
```